# Is it possible to find the closest point that is on Google Street View

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api, google

I have a program that outputs a coordinate (42.12576, 13.12356 for example), is it possible to find the closest point to that that is on Google Street View using the API, or something like that. I'm using Python for my program.

Comment: are you asking based on the given lat long you want the closest GSV point? or google maps in general?

Comment: @ziggy yes, closest point that is on GSV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when using the Street View Static API you can specify both a location and a maximum radius in which the API should search for an image.

> `location` can be either a text string (such as `Chagrin Falls, OH`) or a
> lat/lng value (`40.457375,-80.009353`) [...]
>
> [...]
> `radius` (default is `50`) sets a radius, specified in meters, in which to
> search for a panorama, centered on the given latitude and longitude. [...]

An example request would be `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=23,42&radius=1234&key=YOUR_API_KEY&signature=YOUR_SIGNATURE`

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/request-streetview for more information.

To get not the image but metadata including its location you can use the metadata endpoint which returns JSON. An example request would be  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?size=600x300&location=23,42&radius=1234&key=YOUR_API_KEY&signature=YOUR_SIGNATURE`

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata for more information.